Configuration 'development' is not set in the workspace. In Angular 17 existing project
I have added ng add @angular/ssr in my existing Angular 17 project.
When I run command npm run dev:ssr, I'm getting this error:

This is a simple server for use in testing or debugging Angular applications locally.
It hasn't been reviewed for security issues.
DON'T USE IT FOR PRODUCTION!
Configuration 'development' is not set in the workspace.

package.json
{
  "name": "farmQ",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "dev:ssr": "ng run farmQ:serve-ssr",
    "serve:ssr": "node dist/farmQ/server/main.js",
    "build:ssr": "ng build && ng run farmQ:server",
    "prerender": "ng run farmQ:prerender"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@ag-grid-community/angular": "^31.0.0",
    "@angular/animations": "^17.3.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "^16.2.14",
    "@angular/common": "^17.3.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "^17.3.2",
    "@angular/core": "^17.3.2",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^15.0.0-beta.42",
    "@angular/forms": "^17.3.2",
    "@angular/material": "^16.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^17.3.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^17.3.2",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^17.3.2",
    "@angular/router": "^17.3.2",
    "@angular/ssr": "^17.3.2",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^14.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "ag-grid-angular": "^28.2.1",
    "ag-grid-community": "^28.2.1",
    "angularx-qrcode": "^17.0.0",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.1580.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.3",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.7.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "mock-browser": "^0.92.14",
    "moment": "^2.30.1",
    "ng-material-multilevel-menu": "^6.0.2",
    "ng-otp-input": "^1.9.3",
    "ngx-moment": "^6.0.2",
    "ngx-toastr": "^16.2.0",
    "primeflex": "^3.3.1",
    "primeicons": "^6.0.1",
    "primeng": "^17.12.0",
    "rxjs": "^7.4.0",
    "save": "^2.9.0",
    "sweetalert2": "^11.10.6",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "xlsx": "^0.18.5",
    "zone.js": "~0.14.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^17.3.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~17.3.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^17.3.2",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.29",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.17.0",
    "@types/node": "^18.18.0",
    "@types/qrcode": "^1.5.5",
    "browser-sync": "^3.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.3.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "typescript": "~5.4.3"
  }
}

angular.json
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "farmQ": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss",
          "strict": true
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/farmQ/browser",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/web.config"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css",
              "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/saga-blue/theme.css",
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/nova/theme.css",
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
              "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "node_modules/primeflex/primeflex.css",
              "node_modules/sweetalert2/src/sweetalert2.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "vendorChunk": true,
            "extractLicenses": false,
            "buildOptimizer": false,
            "sourceMap": true,
            "optimization": false,
            "namedChunks": true,
            "allowedCommonJsDependencies": [
              "lodash",
              "moment",
              "qrcode",
              "sweetalert2"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "dev": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.dev.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": {
                "scripts": true,
                "styles": {
                  "minify": true,
                  "inlineCritical": false
                },
                "fonts": true
              },
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "13mb",
                  "maximumError": "13mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "13mb",
                  "maximumError": "13mb"
                }
              ]
            },
            "qa": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.qa.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": {
                "scripts": true,
                "styles": {
                  "minify": true,
                  "inlineCritical": false
                },
                "fonts": true
              },
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "13mb",
                  "maximumError": "13mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "13mb",
                  "maximumError": "13mb"
                }
              ]
            },
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": {
                "scripts": true,
                "styles": {
                  "minify": true,
                  "inlineCritical": false
                },
                "fonts": true
              },
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "13mb",
                  "maximumError": "13mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "13mb",
                  "maximumError": "13mb"
                }
              ]
            },
            "staging": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.stag.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": {
                "scripts": true,
                "styles": {
                  "minify": true,
                  "inlineCritical": false
                },
                "fonts": true
              },
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "13mb",
                  "maximumError": "13mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "13mb",
                  "maximumError": "13mb"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": ""
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "port": 5000,
            "host": "0.0.0.0",
            "buildTarget": "farmQ:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "buildTarget": "farmQ:build:production"
            },
            "dev": {
              "buildTarget": "farmQ:build:dev"
            },
            "qa": {
              "buildTarget": "farmQ:build:qa"
            },
            "staging": {
              "buildTarget": "farmQ:build:staging"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "buildTarget": "farmQ:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/web.config"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "farmQ:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "farmQ:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "server": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/farmQ/server",
            "main": "server.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.server.json",
            "buildOptimizer": false,
            "optimization": false,
            "sourceMap": true,
            "extractLicenses": false,
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "vendorChunk": true
          },
          "configurations": {
            "dev": {
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "outputHashing": "media",
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.dev.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false
            },
            "qa": {
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "outputHashing": "media",
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.qa.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false
            },
            "production": {
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "outputHashing": "media",
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false
            },
            "staging": {
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "outputHashing": "media",
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.stag.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve-ssr": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:ssr-dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "farmQ:build:development",
              "serverTarget": "farmQ:server:development"
            },
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "farmQ:build:production",
              "serverTarget": "farmQ:server:production"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "prerender": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:prerender",
          "options": {
            "routes": [
              "/"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "farmQ:build:production",
              "serverTarget": "farmQ:server:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "farmQ:build:development",
              "serverTarget": "farmQ:server:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "analytics": "352769b2-c967-4d4a-8358-edf953619ff9"
  }
}


What's your question? I don't think the message you get is an error, but a warning that you shouldn't be using this in production.

Seems like your angular.json does not have a development configuration. you can add or replace it with the stage. Hope it might help

Can you mark my comment as answer?

That is just a warning not to run the angular server in a production environment, and you should server your application some other way (such as a CDN). It should have no impact on running your application locally.

Sorry, but I have the same problem and I don't get it....
In the angular.json is a development configuration set:
    "serve-ssr": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:ssr-dev-server",
      "configurations": {
        "development": {
          "browserTarget": "farmQ:build:development",
          "serverTarget": "farmQ:server:development"
        },

So what is meant by: Configuration 'development' is not set in the workspace?
When I execute "npm run dev:ssr" the server is not started on my local machine

I found a solution here:
https://github.com/angular/universal/issues/2158
Change server-ssr block in angular.json to:
        "serve-ssr": {
          "builder": "@nguniversal/builders:ssr-dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "app:build",
            "serverTarget": "app:server"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "app:build:production",
              "serverTarget": "app:server:production"
            }
          }
        },

